# Azure Pipeline Get Application Client ID in Script

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-cli

I have a Pipeline in my DevOps that builds and deploys an application. This is working successfully.
As part of the deployment I need to update a configuration.json file with the Client ID of my application. To achieve this I am executing:

```
$clientID = az ad app list --display-name "MyApplication" --query [0].appId
```

I have created an "Azure CLI" step and am executing this within the role of a Service Principal, but when it runs I get an error "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation". Where or what permissions to I need to change?

Pipeline Step Description:

- Azure CLI
- Type: Powershell Core
- Script Path: A Valid Path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other answer is only half correct and not good, the *Delegated permission* `Directory.Read.All` in `Microsoft Graph` will not work in this case, giving the `Global Administrator` role to the service principal will work, but this permission is too large, if you don’t want to cause some security issues, try not to use it.

To solve the issue, you just need to give the *Application permission* `Directory.Read.All` of `Azure Active Directory Graph`, you could follow the steps below.

1.Navigate to the `Project Settings` in devops -> `Service connections` -> find the service connection you used -> click `Manage Service Principal`.

[image]

2.Then it will open the Azure AD App page of the service principal, navigate to the `API permissions` -> add the *Application permission* `Directory.Read.All` of `Azure Active Directory Graph` like below(**Note**: It should be `Azure Active Directory Graph`, not `Microsoft Graph`).

[image]

[image]

3. Don' forget to click the `Grant admin consent for xxx` button at last.

[image]

After a while, try the command again, it will work fine.

Comment: Thanks, that was quite extensive and I hadn't clicked the "Grant Admin consent...", but I believe the issue is with running the "az ad app list". I dont seem to have permission to get that detail

Comment: @Adrian The `az ad app list` essentially calls the AAD Graph, so you need to grant the permission in AAD Graph. Please follow my reply, don't miss any step, and you must click the `Grant Admin consent` button, just trust me, I've helped a lot of people solve similar problems.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to run it with success after adding `Directory.ReadAll` permission

[image]

and adding this principal to Global Administrator group.